# Recieving multiple images in the form of byte[] array through datainputStream

Tags: java, arrays, image, byte, datainputstream

Ok so for my server progrma im trying to send 15 images, code:

```
try{
                //t1.start();
                for(int i =1; i<16; i++){
                    baos  = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("myimage"+i+".jpg"));
                    ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", baos);
                    baos.flush();
                    imageInByte=baos.toByteArray();
                    outToClient.write(imageInByte,0,imageInByte.length);
                    outToClient.flush(); 

                    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(imageInByte));             
                    //ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", outToClient);
                }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

This seems to be working ok, its the client side im having problems with. The code for receiving the images:

```
try
            {   

                Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8001);
                DataInputStream inFromServer = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
                System.out.println("networking established");
                byte[] message = new byte[120947];

                while(true){

                inFromServer.read(message);
                BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(message));
                File outputfile = new File("saved1.jpg");
                ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputfile);


                }

            }catch(IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Ok so I know the while(true) loop wont work, ive tried alot of alternatives like an if statement to check the datainputstream for bytes etc, but Im having no joy. Does anyone know how to continuously receive the byte[] arrays from the server? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Java ?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry for not stating. Yes im using java.

Comment: Also In the client code you can see "File outputfile = new File("saved1.jpg");", if I were to get this working I would want each new image to save to the next number i.e saved2.jpg, saved3.jpg etc

Comment: Don't you need some sort of deliminator sequence between images so the client knows when one image has ended and another is beginning?  If you are making up your own protocol, you should create a header for each image, with the header at least indicating the size (in bytes) of the following image so you know when you have reached the end of the image and can start the next image.

Comment: Solved this problem by using an ObjectOutputStream rather than a dataoutputstream.